# how to make different divs appear in the same spot?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three buttons, and I want them to display different text in the same spot to the side on mouseover. I've gotten it to work with one button, but once I added the other two it stopped working. This is the code i used with the first button:

jQuery-

```
document.getElementById('description-text').style.display="none";

$("#description-button").on("mouseenter",function()
{
$("#description-text").fadeIn("slow");
});

$("#description-button").on("mouseleave",function()
{
$("#description-text").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

CSS-

```
#description-text {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

#description-button {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#description-container {
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70%;
    background: transparent;
}

#description-button:hover {
    background-color: #99daea;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

HTML-

```
<!--description-->
  <div id="description-container">
    <div id="description-button"></div>
    <div id="description-text">
     this is a description.
    </div><!--tab-text-->
</div><!--description-container-->
```

the code for the other two buttons is exactly the same, all I did was change the id names and the positioning of the buttons. The first button's text disappears, but I can't get it to show up on mouseover. The other text doesn't disappear at all. You can see it [here](http://mattiethemes.tumblr.com).

Comment: please give me axactly html code with two buttons or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```js
document.getElementById('description-text').style.display="none";

$(".description-button").each(function() {
   $(this).on("mouseenter",function() {
        $("#description-text").fadeIn("slow");
   });
});

$(".description-button").each(function() {
   $(this).on("mouseleave",function() {
        $("#description-text").fadeOut("slow");
   });
});
```

```css
#description-text {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

#description-button1 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#description-button2 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#description-button3 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#description-container {
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70%;
    background: transparent;
}

.description-button:hover {
    background-color: #99daea;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--description-->
  <div id="description-container">
    <div class="description-button" id="description-button1"></div>
    <div class="description-button" id="description-button2"></div>
    <div class="description-button" id="description-button3"></div>
    <div id="description-text">
     this is a description.
    </div><!--tab-text-->
</div><!--description-container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery code to not on show the div, but also fill the div with the right content:

```
document.getElementById('description-text').style.display="none";

$("#description-button").on("mouseenter",function()
{
$("#description-text").html('text from mouseenter 1');
$("#description-text").fadeIn("slow");
});

$("#description-button").on("mouseleave",function()
{
$("#description-text").fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#description-button-2").on("mouseenter",function()
{
$("#description-text").html('text from mouseenter 2');
$("#description-text").fadeIn("slow");
});

$("#description-button-2").on("mouseleave",function()
{
$("#description-text").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier if you use classes, something like this:

```js
$(".button").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).next(".description").fadeIn("slow");
});

$(".button").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).next(".description").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
.description {
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    display: none;
}
.button {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    /*position: absolute;
    left: 200px;*/
    margin-left: 200px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.container {
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70%;
    background: transparent;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #99daea;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="description">this is a</div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="description">this is b</div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="description">this is c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
document.getElementById('description-text').style.display = "none";

$(".description-button").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $("#description-text").text($(this).siblings(".text").text());
    $("#description-text").finish().fadeIn("slow");
});

$(".description-button").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $("#description-text").finish().fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Have a look at [the complete **JSFiddle** demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jr4vc3g/)